# Recursive function output not clear

Tags: java, recursion

```
 public void numbers(int n)
 {
     if(n>0)
     {
         System.out.print(n);
         numbers(n-2);
         System.out.print(n);
     }
 }
```

I have the above code snippet. 
When i call numbers(5)
It gives me an output : 531135

I understood till 531. But after this how can the second print statement be even reached when n<0?? And why is it 135 like this?

I really don't have any clue regarding this and please help me with a detailed explanation and dry run.

If I am asking something silly please forgive me.

Thank you

Comment: Did you notice the `if` statement?

Comment: This sounds like a great opportunity to step through the code in a debugger and observe its behavior.  Why *wouldn't* it output `531135`?  If the first `print()` statement is reached, why do you think the second wouldn't be?  They're in the same block of code.

Comment: System.out.println("1st "+n);
numbers(n-2);
System.out.println("2nd "+n);
Write this, it'll help you to understand

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna try to trace what the program is doing:

```
numbers(5)
  5>0
    print(5)
    numbers(3)
      3>0
        print(3)
        numbers(1)
          1>0
            print(1)
            numbers(-1)
              -1>0
            print(1)
        print(3)
    print(5)
```

As you can see, the second `print`-statement of each function call does not depend on any `if` (the `if` of the recursive call doesn't matter to the calling method). Therefore every number is ALWAYS printed twice (or never).

I hope this is somewhat clear to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a debugger to walk through the program.  Below I modified
your program and added a few `println()` showing the various states
of the program.  I also added `r` to show the recursion level and `__` to 
help indenting the output.  See if this now help you understand 
better.

```
public class NumberRecursion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        numbers(5);

    }

    private static int r = 0;           // recursion level
    private static String __ = "";      // indent prefix
    public static void numbers(int n)
     {
        r++;                            // recursion level
        __ += "    ";                   // indent by another four spaces 

        System.out.println(__+ "[" + r + "] numbers(" + n + ") entered");
         if(n>0)                    // L3
         {
             System.out.println(__+ "["  + r + "] L3 tested true (and n=" + n + ")");
             System.out.println(n); // P1
             System.out.println(__+ "["  + r + "] about to invoke numbers(" + (n-2) + ")");
             numbers(n-2);          // N
             System.out.println(__+ "["  + r + "] numbers(" + (n-2) + ") just finished");
             System.out.println(n); // P2
         } else {
            System.out.println(__+ "[" + r + "] L3 tested false (and n=" + n + ")");
         }
        System.out.println(__+ "["  + r + "] numbers(" + n + ") about to return");
        __ = __.substring(0, __.length()-4);
                                        // indent now has four less spaces
        r--;                            // recursion level
     }


}
```

The output of this program would be this.  In this output, the number in square
brackets (e.g. `[1]`) is the level of recursion.

```
    [1] numbers(5) entered
    [1] L3 tested true (and n=5)
5
    [1] about to invoke numbers(3)
        [2] numbers(3) entered
        [2] L3 tested true (and n=3)
3
        [2] about to invoke numbers(1)
            [3] numbers(1) entered
            [3] L3 tested true (and n=1)
1
            [3] about to invoke numbers(-1)
                [4] numbers(-1) entered
                [4] L3 tested false (and n=-1)
                [4] numbers(-1) about to return
            [3] numbers(-1) just finished
1
            [3] numbers(1) about to return
        [2] numbers(1) just finished
3
        [2] numbers(3) about to return
    [1] numbers(3) just finished
5
    [1] numbers(5) about to return
```

Comment: What is the logic it is coming 1 then 3 and then 5...i cannot understand this stuff...and why consecutive p2...how n is changing in this manner

Comment: It's somewhat like a LIFO in stack....is it some internal behavior of java which uses such mechanism??

Comment: @Arpan -- I updated my answer.  See if you can understand the program better now.

Comment: Thank you sir, so this a stack like something keeping travk of the unreachable statements right???

Comment: @Arpan -- Yes, function calls (including recursive function calls) are implemented by pushing information on a stack.  C.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack